# Django model methods(Date filter)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Been struggling for weeks now with this issue, starting to feel like I will never solve it.

I have these methods under my model.

```
 def sfget_totals(self):
        return self.agent_sale.filter(Date_created__range=["2022-03-01","2022-04-02"]).count()
 def sfget_confirmed(self):
        return self.agent_sale.filter(State="Confirmed",Date_created__range=["2022-03-01","2022-04-02"]).count()
 def sfget_debi(self):
        return self.agent_sale.filter(AcknowledgeQA=True,State="Confirmed",Debi_status="Accepted",Date_created__range=["2022-03-01","2022-04-02"]).count()
 def sfget_requested(self):
        return self.agent_sale.filter(Debi_status="Requested",Date_created__range=["2022-03-01","2022-04-02"]).count()
 def sfget_cancelled(self):
        return self.agent_sale.filter(State="Cancelled",Date_created__range=["2022-03-01","2022-04-02"]).count()
 def sfget_pending(self):
        return self.agent_sale.filter(State="Pending",Date_created__range=["2022-03-01","2022-04-02"]).count()
```

in the above example i am putting the dates in manually(it works and returns the correct query)
problem is I still don't know how to make the user plug these dates in through the site.

This is my view.

```
def Team_stats(request,pk):
    sd = request.GET.get("from")
    ed = request.GET.get("to")
    start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(sd, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
    end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(ed, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
    if start_date == None or end_date == None:
        sales_agent = SalesAgent.objects.filter(Team_leader=pk)
        return render(request,"Sales/Team_detail_page.html",{"sales_agent":sales_agent})
    else:
        sales_agent = SalesAgent.objects.filter(Team_leader=pk,agent_sale__Date_created__range=[start_date,end_date]).distinct()
        print(type(start_date))
        return render(request,"Sales/Team_detail_page.html",{"sales_agent":sales_agent})
```

This is my template.
I need to render all the agents under the team leader and the particular field of another model. For example State,Date_Created,Debi_status.

```
<form method="GET" action=".">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputEmail4">Start date</label>
      <input type="date" format='%Y-%m-%d' name="from" class="form-control"  id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Start Date">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputEmail4">End date</label>
      <input type="date" format='%Y-%m-%d' name="to" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="End date">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
</form>
<!-- <p>THERE SHOULD BE A GRAPH IN HERE FOR THE AGENTS STATS</p> -->
<br>
<br>
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-dark table-striped table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">Agent Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Total sales</th>
          <th scope="col">Total debis</th>
          <th scope="col">Total confirmed</th>
          <th scope="col">Total requested</th>
          <th scope="col">Total pending</th>
          <th scope="col">Total cancelled</th>      
        </tr>
      </thead>
      {% for entry in sales_agent %}
      <tbody>
<td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
<td>{{entry.SA_name}}</td>
<td>{{entry.sfget_totals}}</td>
<td>{{ entry.sfget_debi}}</td>
<td>{{ entry.sfget_confirmed}}</td>
<td>{{ entry.sfget_requested}}</td>
<td>{{ entry.sfget_cancelled}}</td>
<td>{{ entry.sfget_pending}}</td>

{%endfor%}  
</table>
<div>
  <a type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-m" href="{%url 'Sales:salesdash'%}">Go back</a>
{%endblock%}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it better. It's not the best answer because you have to iterate through the entire queryset. But I think it works:

1- Change your models methods adding the variables "from" and "to":

```
#example
def sfget_totals(self, from, to): #
    return self.agent_sale.filter(Date_created__range=[from,to]).count()
```

2- In your views.py, iterate and add the new properties to each item of the queryset:

```
def Team_stats(request,pk):
    sd = request.GET.get("from")
    ed = request.GET.get("to")
    start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(sd, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
    end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(ed, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
    if start_date == None or end_date == None:
        sales_agent = SalesAgent.objects.filter(Team_leader=pk)
        return render(request,"Sales/Team_detail_page.html",{"sales_agent":sales_agent})
    else:
        sales_agent = SalesAgent.objects.filter(Team_leader=pk,agent_sale__Date_created__range=[start_date,end_date])
        for s in sales_agent:
            s.sfget_totals_prop = s.sfget_totals(start_date,end_date)
            s.sfget_confirmed_prop = s.sfget_confirmed(start_date,end_date)
            s.sfget_debi_prop = s.sfget_debi(start_date,end_date)
            ....
            ....                
        return render(request,"Sales/Team_detail_page.html",{"sales_agent":sales_agent})
```

3- In your templates, change the methods name by the new properties:

```
<td>{{entry.sfget_totals_prop}}</td>
<td>{{ entry.sfget_debi_prop}}</td>
<td>{{ entry.sfget_confirmed_prop}}</td>
<td>{{ entry.sfget_requested_prop}}</td>
<td>{{ entry.sfget_cancelled_prop}}</td>
<td>{{ entry.sfget_pending_prop}}</td>
```

Probably, you can solve the problem using Django Managers https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/managers/ and you will find a better way.

Comment: Hi thanks but this did not fix the problem. i need the values the user inputs from and to date to return, meaning the model method requires dates BUT it only works if i manually plug them in. how do i do this.

Comment: Ok, now I understand the problem. I am editing my answer

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, that is exactly what i was looking for! it works exactly as i need it to work, i cannot thank you enough! God bless